# How to get only the last 5 numbers from a line found in a text file by findstr command?

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I want to get the *last 5 Numbers* of a *FindStr* command from the displayed output of a *txt* file.

This is my command:

```
FindStr "lastServer" C:\Users\Defcon1\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\.options.txt
```

An example for a displayed output is:

```
lastServer:111.111.111.111:53680
```

How to get just the 5 numbers (IP address and port number) without the string `lastServer:` from the output line?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple task and easy to code as shown below:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "OptionsFile=%APPDATA%\.minecraft\.options.txt"

rem Does the file exist at all?
if not exist "%OptionsFile%" (
    echo Error: File %OptionsFile% not found!
    goto EndBatch
)

rem Search for last server line in file and get IP address and port number.
set "IP_and_Port="
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe "lastServer" "%OptionsFile%" 2^>nul') do set "IP_and_Port=%%J"

rem Was IP and port number found in file?
if "%IP_and_Port%" == "" (
    echo Error: Found in file %OptionsFile%
    echo        no line with string "lastServer" with an IP address and a port number!
    goto EndBatch
)

rem Output found data.
echo Found: %IP_and_Port%

:EndBatch
endlocal
pause
```

Another solution without using the command **FINDSTR** is:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "OptionsFile=%APPDATA%\.minecraft\.options.txt"

rem Does the file exist at all?
if not exist "%OptionsFile%" (
    echo Error: File %OptionsFile% not found!
    goto EndBatch
)

rem Search for last server line in file and get IP address and port number.
for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=:" %%I in ("%OptionsFile%") do (
    if /I "%%I" == "lastServer" (
        set "IP_and_Port=%%J"
        goto DataFound
    )
)

echo Error: Found in file %OptionsFile%
echo        no line with string "lastServer" with an IP address and a port number!
goto EndBatch

rem Output found data.
:DataFound
echo Found: %IP_and_Port%

:EndBatch
endlocal
pause
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`